# Django admin dashboard CSS is missing

Tags: python, django, deployment

I just deployed my application to DigitalOcean. Everything works very well, excep admin panel's styling although I've used nginx. Here are my codes:

`settings.py`:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static_root")

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
]
```

nginx configuration:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name server_domain_or_IP;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static_root/ {
        root /home/my_username/myproject;
    }

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/home/my_username/myproject/myproject.sock;
    }
}
```

Comment: did you run python manage.py collectstatic?  Is DEBUG = True on the server in the settings file for Django?  if so, this may be why you are not seeing css render in admin.

Comment: @ja408 problem was in static_root folder name, thank you.

Comment: ah ok.  Static files tend to be a snag for a lot of people, including myself.